# How to identify the RAM address space in windows operating system?

Tags: c, windows, operating-system, ram, memory-address

If I create a variable say:

```
int a[10];
```

I am creating a variable and using he address space of the above variable to store the values. So how to identify the address space for the above variable ??

Comment: Are you asking for variable address? If yes - addres of first element is just **a** and addresses of other elements is just **&a[index]**. But how you 'ask' for this address has implications later if you use this address and how so gave you just simplified answer here.

Comment: @Artur : How to identify the RAM address space in windows operating system ??

Comment: @sachin s: What do you mean by "RAM address space in windows operating system"? If you need physical address - you'll not get it. These will all be virtual addresses anyways.

Comment: Hoe to get a fixed address for the above variable in the RAM ??

Comment: If you want to know the physical location in RAM, you can only do that from kernel mode. Why do you want that?

Comment: @Gabe: Thank you very much for the reply. I am initializing the variable and later transferring some values to the specific variable. To do this, I should know the address of the variable. I will be storing the address of the variable and then when the task started executing the values will be stored in that address of the variable.

Comment: There is an A2L file (where I can store only an address of the variable and later I can transfer the value back to that particular address of a variable) So I should know the address of the variable .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print address of a variable do

```
int a[10];
int i;
int *p = &i;
printf("Address of a : %p \n", (void *)a);
printf("Address of i : %p \n", (void *)&i);

//to update i using pointer do
*p = 100; //or even p[0] = 100;


//a is array which is actually a pointer so you can update its elements as
a[0] = 10; //for 1st elem
a[1] = 100; //for 2nd elem etc.
//you can do this too
p = a;
p[0] = 10;
p[1] = 100;
```

If you mean to get actual physical address, its not easily available.

Comment: Yes, but with a cast, `printf("Address of a : %p \n", (void *)a);`

Comment: Hoe to get a fixed address for the above variable in the RAM ??

Comment: @sachins, what do you mean by fixed address?

Comment: if I initialize like int a[10];  then how to get the address of the variable a in the RAM's space ?? Later I use the same address space to store the value.

Comment: @sachin: You must work on clarity of your questions. They are totally weird hence SO users cannot get what you are asking about - everyone is guessing. Please at least read **ANSI C** (in english not a translation). This should help you to write better questions with proper terminology etc.

Comment: @Artur : Thank you very much for the reply. My question : if I initialize like int a[10]; then how to get the address of the variable a in the RAM's memory ?? Later I use the same address space to store the value.

Comment: @sachin: Sorry buddy -if other user's answers have not explained what you ask for I cannot help you now as simply do not understand your question. Just read ANSI C - it will help you http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1384168187&sr=1-2&keywords=ansi+c

Comment: @sachins, I have updated my answer. Check if thats is what you are looking for. Otherwise, update question with more detail about question.

Comment: @Rohan: I understood the above program and if I run the above code then i will be getting different address for running everytime. Is it possible to assign a specific address to the variable in RAM ??

Comment: @sachins, no you can't assign specific address to variable in RAM.

Comment: why is it not possible ??

Comment: @sachin because that is how the C language is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The memory address of the array will range from address of a[0] to address of a[9]. You can get the starting address by using `&a[0]`.

[Address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) is the range of addresses which refer to different hardware components like RAM, io devices, etc.

Comment: Hoe to get a fixed address for the above variable in the RAM ??

Comment: What do you mean by 'fixed address'? Each time you run the program you are allocated different region of the memory. The address of variables are not fixed; they change with each new instance. Also, you cannot get the absolute addresses; only virtual addresses.

Comment: why am I not able to get the absolute address ??

Comment: if I initialize like int a[10]; then how to get the address of the variable a in the RAM's space ?? Later I use the same address space to store the value

Comment: You can get the memory address by using the '&' operator. You cannot decide the memory address where objects will be stored; it is decided at run time by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin - if you are writing your code for embedded system without virtual memory you can write literally physical address location. For example if you want to write some memory mapped register etc which is 8 bit long and at address 0x123 you may do that this way:

```
*((unsigned char*)0x123) = 45;
```

What it will do is write value 45 (decimal) to physical address 0x123.

The meaning of:

```
 *((unsigned char*)0x123)
```

is as follows:

```
(unsigned char*)0x123 // cast value 0x123 to pointer to unsigned char
```

which means treat 0x123 as address to unsigned 8 bit value

and the whole stuff:

```
*((unsigned char*)0x123) = 45;
```

will use pointer aquired with (unsigned char*)0x123 to write value 45 to address 0x123.

In general (**on embedded systems**):

```
// assuming:
//  C - pointer to 8bit entity
//  S - pointer to 16bit entity
//  I - pointer to 32bit entity
*(C) = 8bit_val;   // will write 8bit **value** to physical address pointed by C
*(S) = 16bit_val;  // will write 16bit **value** to physical address pointed by S
*(I) = 32bit_val;  // will write 32bit **value** to physical address pointed by I
```

This is really simplified but this will do what you want.
If you want to put an array, structure or regular variable at specific physical address it can be done on embedded systems (you must read about scatter loading on ARM compiler for example). Sccater file will allow you to place your **a** array on any location that you want and you'll be able to access it using regular syntax without using pointers explicitly.

However on Windows platform you'll not be able to do that as you are not working with pysical addresses but with so called virtual memory where you have some value that theoretically is an address but it is not related to physical address. It is just too broad to explain. It's huge subject.

Here is some info about [scatter loading](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Chddbefb.html)